# streamreader getting very slow for large files, how to make it fast

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I m newbie in c#, and making project to transfer files, if i am transferring a file about 10mb, its taking less then 5seconds to transfer, when file size is above 100mb, it takes 1min, i m testing within localhost, and found streamreader is getting very slow to transfer large file, is there any way to improve performance.

my code is below:

```
    protected byte[] GetRequestInput()
    {
        StreamReader _inputStream = new StreamReader(base.HttpApplication.Request.InputStream);

        long _inputSize = _inputStream.BaseStream.Length;

        byte[] _inputBytes = new byte[_inputSize];
        _inputStream.BaseStream.Read(_inputBytes, 0, (int)_inputSize);
        return _inputBytes;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're using `streamreader`. You're rirectly using underlying stream

Comment: If it takes 5 seconds for a 10 MB file then a file that's ten times larger will take ten times longer.  So sure, 50 seconds is about a minute, especially if you wait for it.

Comment: Don't use the `StreamReader`. Just read from `HttpApplication.Request.InputStream` directly.

Comment: I tested with breakpoint, its taking lot of time to collect data from HttpApplication.Request.InputStream, how to make it fast?